# How do I switch the app on top while I'm in split screen mode?

Tags: android-11, oneplus, multi-window

For example, I wanted to open the game app on the bottom screen while I switch apps on the top screen. The problem is when I open the first app on top screen, it does not allow me to switch apps. It only allows me to resize the screen  Is there any way i can make the first app on top to switch to other apps?

Comment: Can you enlist your phone's model and android version? Personally, I don't think you can do anything but to go to home screen and start the split screen again.